# Nuxt 3 not rendering in SSR

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

So I am having an issue, I am trying to get my private env variables. I know that I can only get them when my page is ssr. The thing is that I have never disabled it. I am logging in my pages `console.log(process.server)` and this always returns `false`. What I find pretty weird because I have never disabled ssr.

This is my nuxt.config.ts:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: true,
    routeRules: {
        '/portal/**': { ssr: false },
        '/checkout/**': { ssr: false }
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
        stripeKey: '',
        public: {
            API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL || "http://192.168.1.100:8000/api",
        }
    },
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/i18n',
        '@pinia/nuxt',
    ],
    css: [
        '@/assets/css/main.css',
        '@/assets/css/colors.scss',
        'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass',
        'primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css',
        'primevue/resources/primevue.css',
        'primeicons/primeicons.css',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
    ],
    build: {
        transpile: [
            'primevue',
            'vuetify'
        ]
    },
    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            tailwindcss: {},
            autoprefixer: {},
        },
    },
    app: {
        head: {
            script: [{ src: "https://js.stripe.com/v3/" }],
            title: '',
            meta: [

                {
                    name: 'color-scheme',
                    content: 'only light'
                }

            ],
            link: [
                {
                    href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined',
                    rel: 'stylesheet',
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    i18n: {
        lazy: true,
        langDir: "locales",
        strategy: "no_prefix",
        locales: [
            {
                code: 'en',
                iso: 'en',
                name: 'English',
                file: 'en.json'
            },
            {
                code: 'nl-Nl',
                iso: 'nl-NL',
                name: 'Dutch',
                file: 'nl-NL.json'
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your browser (also known as "the client-side"), `console.log(process.server)` will always log `false`.

Take a look at your server console in the terminal. There it should be logged too (with `true`), unless you do the log in a "client-only" component/plugin or in a lifecycle hook like `onMounted`.